# Video is not visible on the page, while importing video in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-dom

Video is not visible on the page, while importing video in React.

Video.js

```
import React from "react";

function Video() {
  return (
    <div className="video">
      <video width="320" height="240" autoplay>
        <source src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nfs1vsDlrxI"></source>
        Your browser does not support the video tag
      </video>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Video;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olrWx.png)

Here is the network section, where I can see that video status code 200.

(I have already import my Video.js file in App.js)

Comment: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nfs1vsDlrxI` is not the URL of a video, it is the URL of an HTML page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nfs1vsDlrxI` is not a valid video url! also we can not access direct link of video from youtube.

for using of youtube video you need get embedded code from youtube then add it to your page :

[image]

check this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-zhukovsky-m8i2wi?file=/src/App.js)

```
function Video() {
  return (
    <div className="video">
      <iframe
        width="560"
        height="315"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Nfs1vsDlrxI"
        title="YouTube video player"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
        allowfullscreen
      ></iframe>
    </div>
  );
}
```